# Как запустить сайт локально на apache2 в ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, virtual-hosts

Я установил Lamp сервер на ubuntu.
Скопировал стандартный виртуальный хост 000-default.conf в sites-aviabled,
файл называется mysite.conf. Поправил в нём конфигурацию, указал путь до папки сайта. Выполнил в терминале

```
a2ensite mysite && service apache2 restart
```

Как теперь открыть сайт в браузере ?, по какому домену. Я пробывал прописать в хостах

127.0.0.1   mysite

Так "Невозможно установить подключение" , не работает =(
Как это делается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помимо всего прочего, вам требуется раскомментировать строку с директивой `ServerName`. В вашем случае она должна выглядеть так:

```
ServerName mysite
```

В браузере необходимо обращаться по адресу http://mysite

**Общая схема**, добавление нового виртуального хоста в `apache2`:

1) Создать новый файл в директории `sites-available`, с названием `servername.conf`.

2) В него вставить подобный код:

ServerName servername
    DocumentRoot /var/www/servername

3) Затем выполнить в терминале

sudo a2ensite servername
   sudo systemctl reload apache2

4) В файле `/etc/hosts` добавить строку:
   127.0.0.1    servername

5) Открыть в браузере по адресу `servername`

Comment: Точно , ServerName не указал, спасибо!